# Using nested IF function in excel: is there a way to check next row for same IF function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have a simplified table of only 2 columns. Column one is Group number, with groups of different sizes. Column 2 is also numbered but has a lot of blanks.

I basically want to fill these blanks with the next NOT blank, if it is still in the same first-column-group.

I don't know if it works to show a table here, but this is what it is now and what I want to achieve with a simplified dataset:

[image: What my data looks like now]

[image: How I want it to look]

What I tried is to use an If function. First, it checks if B1 is blank. If it is blank, I want it to check if A1 is the same "group" value as A2. If that is also true, then I want the formula to return me the value of B2. However, if B2 is also blank I want it to loop: Check if A1/A2 are the same as A3, and then give the value of B3. And continue. Plus! If B1 is not blank to begin with it just needs to return the value B1. And if B1 is blank but A1 is not the same group as A2, I want it to remain blank (or 0 is also fine).

The only way I did this was making an extremely nested if function that kept repeating for the [if true] part, which looks like this:

```
=IF(B2="";(IF(A2=A3;
(IF(B3="";(IF(A3=A4;
(IF(B4="";(IF(A4=A5;
(IF(B5="";(IF(A5=A6;
(IF(B6="";(IF(A6=A7;
(IF(B7="";(IF(A7=A8;
(IF(B8="";(IF(A8=A9;"xx";""))
;B8));""));B7));""));B6));""));B5));""));B4));""));B3));""));B2)
```

However, sometimes there are 100+ blanks within one group, and I'm trying to avoid looping 100+ repetitions of that formula.Right now, when there are not enough loops for within a group, it shows the xx. Is there no way to just replace the B1 by a continuous string of cells of column B? I looked at the Row function but it only works when you pull it down if I understand it correctly.

Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: your best bet will be vba not formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to try a formula, something like this will work:

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2,IFERROR(INDEX(B2:B$19,MATCH(A2,IF(B2:B$19<>"",A2:A$19),0)),""))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> in my version of Excel (2019).

[image]

The inner IF statement produces an array where only the rows that have a number in column B will have a value equal to the group value in column A, otherwise it will default to FALSE, so you get

```
False
False
1
False
1
False
False
2
False
...
```

then you do a Match on the value of A which is in the current row in the array to find the next row where there is a non-blank value in column B (3 in the first case). Then Index produces the corresponding value from column B in the row found by the Match (1 in the first case).

If the match fails because there are no further entries in the current group (like in rows 15 and 16 of the screenshot) then it will call in the "" from the IFERROR statement, so you get a blank in that row.

You could change the IFERROR to zero if you preferred to have zeroes in those cells rather than blanks:

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2,IFERROR(INDEX(B2:B$19,MATCH(A2,IF(B2:B$19<>"",A2:A$19),0)),0))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for taking the time. But I don't completely understand it, could you explain why row 15 and 16 now return blank?

Comment: I will add it to my answer. You may find this too slow though if you have thousands of rows of data, I am aiming to add a more efficient version as well but that might not be till later.